# Determine AD password policy programmatically

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have been using the `System.DirectoryService` (ADSI) classes and methods to create and change users in an Active Directory.

Recently we added a feature to allow users to set their own password through the system. However, using the `SetPassword` method throws an exception when the password is not accepted by the Password Policy set.

```
userEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] {password});
```

My question is: How do I check to see if a password lives up to the password policy, before attempting to use the SetPassword-method?

I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313859/reading-the-local-password-policy-programmatically) that you can get the Password Policy-settings from the root domain node, but where can I read more about what each attribute means? For instance, which characters are required to fullfill the "Complexity" policy?

Once I know this, I can implement my own password check-method, but as this is an error-prone approach, I would rather use a built-in check and give the user appropriate info on what is wrong with their password.

Comment: Have you found a good solution to this? I am working on a solution for doing the validation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060251/validate-new-ad-password-according-to-local-security-policy) so being able to lookup the current policy would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API function you want is **[NetValidatePasswordPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netvalidatepasswordpolicy)**.

There are three modes it operates in:

- **`NetValidateAuthentication`**: if you are authenticating a user; so the function can check password expiration policies, bad login attempts, account lockouts, bad login attempts, etc
- **`NetValidatePasswordChange`**: if the user is changing their password; so the function can check against lockout, or against the password policy

and the mode you want:

- **`NetValidatePasswordReset`**: you are an admin resetting a user's password; which only checks the password complexity.

I'll try transcoding from another language to C# on the fly; but you will have to P/Invoke it.

```
<summary>Check password during password reset.

    The result from NetValidatePasswordReset, this member can be one of the following values.

        NERR_Success                        The password passes the validation check.
        NERR_PasswordTooShort           Validation failed. The password does not meet policy requirements because it is too short.
        NERR_PasswordTooLong                Validation failed. The password does not meet policy requirements because it is too long.
        NERR_PasswordNotComplexEnough   Validation failed. The password does not meet policy requirements because it is not complex enough.
        NERR_PasswordFilterError        Validation failed. The password does not meet the requirements of the password filter DLL.
</summary>
UInt32 TestPasswordComplexity(String username, SecureString password)
{
   //All code on stack overflow is in the public domain; no attribution
   //is required.
   const UInt32 NetValidatePasswordReset = 3;

   NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_RESET_INPUT_ARG args = new NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_RESET_INPUT_ARG();
   args.UserAccountName = Username; //some policies check that your password cannot contain your username
   args.ClearPassword = SecureStringToString(password);

   PNET_VALIDATE_OUTPUT_ARG res;

   DWORD le = NetValidatePasswordPolicy(null, null, NetValidatePasswordReset, @args, {out}Pointer(res));

   if (le <> NERR_Success)
      throw new WindowsException(le); //

   return res.ValidationStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a similar project at my work.  We are rolling a forgot password application.  I ended up just doing an `Invoke("SetPassword", "[randomString]")` and saved the random string for the `Invoke("ChangePassword","[randomString]","[user supplied pw]")`. The result of the `ChangePassword` was returned to the user.

SetPassword does not check for password complexity or history rules. It is the same as right clicking a user in AD and selecting "Reset Password."  `ChangePassword` however, does check for password history requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity policy is that it must contain three out of five of these types:

- Upper case letters
- Lower case letters
- Digits
- Non-alphanumeric characters: ~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|(){}[]:;"'<>,.?/
- Unicode characters that are alphabetics but not uppercase or lowercase.

It also can't be the sAMAccountName or displayName (or parts of).  You can read about it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468%28WS.10%29.aspx).  The other password policy rules are in [adjacent documents](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783512%28WS.10%29.aspx).

You could try setting it and catch exceptions but from memory I don't think it tells you what's wrong with the password, just that it doesn't meet the requirements.