# Check Password against Active Directory Policy

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a frontend which allows the User to change it's AD Password.

1. Is there a Way to get the password policy (for example fine grained) for a specific user and its properties (Length, Complexity...)
2. Is there a Way to check the string "xyz121" against this specific policy?

EDIT:
I don't want to check against the current password stored in the active directory.
I want to check if the new password would could be safed into active directory.
For Example: User types in his NEW password "xyz121" and wants to change it but active directory just allows passwords with at least 8 chars.

Comment: Nope not a duplicate. I don't want to check if the current password. I want to validate a new one.
See edit ;-)

Comment: @Adriano Not a duplicate definitely. The question is different.

Comment: The answer with higher score gives the hint. You have the Principal and you call the ChangePassword() method (instead of Validate). Wrong password will generate PasswordException.

Answer (score 1):

Trailing through SO and google came up with this -
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david_leblanc/archive/2007/10/11/checking-password-complexity.aspx

Started from this SO post - [Determine AD password policy programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992474/determine-ad-password-policy-programmatically)

Which led to this SO answer -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10549823/416574

which led to that above blog post.  Hope that helps.

(Feel free to not upvote, this just seemed like too much text for a comment, but really no work here but googling).

Comment: Original link has now rotted - 403